# Modifying MapEditor - uDig Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, gis, rich-client-platform

I am currently working on a research project utilizing uDig.

I am trying using the MapEditor class to display an interactive map that displays real-time scheduling.

The current problem I am experiencing relates to the open-save-close life-cycle of the MapEditor class.  Every time the user starts the program, I want there to only be one MapEditor in the workbench, however, when the application opens, the program brings up the old MapEditor as well.  Added to this are a few other features that I would like to be able to disable.  I would like the user to be able to close the entire application without the program asking if the user would like to save the map.  I would also like to disable the asterisk that displays when the editor "isDirty".

After a little bit of searching, I found a thread on the refractions forum that related to the same problem I am experiencing, however the poster never revealed his/her final solution (if any).

Any ideas on how to correct these problems in the least invasive way.

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Do you not want saving supported at all? You could override `isDirty()` in your editor to report false always.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  You are correct, I want to avoid saving any data at all, however I have thought about removing all the layers from the map before it is saved to reduce the size of the data stored.  Since we are using uDig, extending MapEditor is not advisable from what I have seen online.  Have you had any experience extending MapEditor?